# Dozer copy-by-reference not working

Tags: java, dozer

I have entities created by `jpa` tool and I have similar DTO's when I fetch  entity from DB and try to mapping using dozer.

entities and DTO look like

```
class A                             class A1
        {                                   {
            private B b;                        private B1 b1;
            private C c;                        private C1 c;

            getter/setter                       getter/setter
        }

        class B                             class B1
        {                                   {                   
            private C c;                     private C1 c;

            getter/setter                       getter/setter
        }                                   }

        class C                             class C1
        {                                   {           
            private A a;                    private A1 a;
            private B b;                    private B1 b;

            getter/setter                   getter/setter
        }                                   }
```

Dozer mapping file looks like:

```
<mapping>
        <class-a>com.entity.A</class-a>
        <class-b>com.dto.A1</class-b>         
          <field copy-by-reference="true">
            <a>b</a>
            <b>b1</b>
          </field>
          <field copy-by-reference="true">
            <a>c</a>
            <b>c1</b>
          </field>
        </mapping>
```

and I am getting exception like:

```
org.dozer.MappingException: Illegal object type for the method 'setb1'. 
 Expected types: 
com.dto.B1
 Actual types: 
com.entity.B
```

I am very new to Dozer please help me to solve this

Comment: The exception pretty much says it all. You have a setter probably in A1 that relieves a B parameter instead of B1.

Comment: yes but how to copy the object type b to b1, i need some suggestion to solve

Comment: When using copy-by-reference they should be the same type. Using this means that No conversion/transformation is done by Dozer, just a simple copy of the same object. It is a way to fine tune performance and avoid objects creation. What is your use case? why do you need copy-by-reference?

Comment: i need to create DTO for every entity and only use entity in DAO layer, in service and controller i have to use DTO only for this i have use dozer mapper to map entity and DTO please suggest me a way to do this

Comment: Your use of Dozer is fine, I'm also using it the same way as you are, however I don't use the "copy-by-reference" property. If you don't really need this ability, Remove the "copy-by-reference" property and it should work (assuming that you don't have any other complex types that Dozer can't transform automatically).

Comment: thank you so much Koby, it works .

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. I've added it as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using copy-by-reference, setters on both entities should be of the same type. Using this means that no conversion/transformation is done by Dozer, just a simple copy of the same object.

If you don't need this ability, remove the "copy-by-reference" property and it should work (assuming that you don't have any other complex types that Dozer can't transform automatically).